# Is $a \sim b$ such that $\gcd(a,b) > 1$ an equivalence relation?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, equivalence-relations

> Is $a \sim b$ such that $\gcd(a,b) > 1$ an equivalence relation?

I know that it's reflexive, since $\gcd(a,a) > 1$. It's also symmetric since $\gcd(a,b) > 1$ iff $\gcd(b,a) > 1$.

However, I'm having trouble figuring out whether it's transitive. I reckon so, since if $a$ divides $b$ and $b$ divides $c$, then $a$ must divide $c$. However when I entered in my university's online quiz that it is an equivalence relation, it marked the answer as wrong. Am I incorrect?

Comment: Are you comfortable with ignoring $1$? :-)

Comment: Ahh I forgot to mention that this is for all a,b > 1.

Comment: @user134758: Then _edit it into your question_!

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**
Check that the transitivity fails with
$$a=5,\; b=15,\; c=3$$

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why I thought my little divisibility conjecture would help. I'm guessing that it doesn't work because if gcd(a,b) > 1, then either b|a or a|b? Rather than just the latter.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Check your divisibility conjecture with $8$ and $12$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ $ For any $\,a,b\,$ there exists $\,c\,$ such that $\,a \sim c,\,\ b\sim c\,$ (e.g. $\,c = ab).\,$ Thus if the relation is transitive then, being symmetric, it is trivial: $\,a\sim c,\,\ c\sim b\,\Rightarrow\, a\sim b,\,$ for all $\,a,b.$

**Remark** $\ $ In other words, [directed sets/preorders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_set) are trivial if symmetric.